# Can you clear a CSS width property so that it uses the "width" HTML attribute?

Tags: css

On a WordPress site I'm working on, the parent theme adds `width: auto` and `height: auto` as a default style to all images. But WordPress uses the `width` and `height` HTML attributes to set the size of images added through the WYSIWYG (ie. `<img src="/blah.png" width="320" height="160">`), and those styles override that. Without touching the parent theme, and ideally without JavaScript, is there a way to preserve that behavior of using the size set through the WYSIWYG? I've tried `width: inherit`, `width: initial`, and `width: unset`, all to no avail.

Comment: The `auto` is causing the issue here. The theme sets those in the CSS, which causes the images to render in their full size instead of what they are set to in the WYSIWYG :/

Answer (score 0):

> Without touching the parent theme, and ideally without JavaScript, is there a way to preserve that behavior of using the size set through the WYSIWYG?

Not that I can think of. But here's a solution using JavaScript that sets the `width` and `height` CSS inline to be equivalent to the attributes WP set.

```js
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

Object.values(imgs).forEach((el) => {
  elWidth = el.getAttribute('width');
  elHeight = el.getAttribute('height');
  el.style.width = `${elWidth}px`;
  el.style.height = `${elHeight}px`;
});
```

```css
img {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x800" width="200" height="200" />
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400" width="200" height="200" />
```